# kivy does not use touchscreen (in ubuntu touchscreen is working correctly)

Tags: kivy, ubuntu-18.04, touchscreen

I got an ubuntu 18.04 lts fresh install on x86. Connected is a iiyama touch screen. Off the box under ubuntu touchscreen support is active and working.
My Kivy app does not work with touchscreen support.

the log output of kivy is

```
[DEBUG  ] Base: Create provider from probesysfs,provider=hidinput
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: using probesysfs!
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: found device: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller at /dev/input/event3
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event3
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event3>
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: <USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller> range ABS X position is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: <USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller> range ABS Y position is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: <USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller> range position X is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: <USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller> range position Y is 0 - 4095
```

I configured in the input section of config.ini (kivy):

```
[input]
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Before, under my last installation I got the kivy app running (using touchscreen) with the same ubuntu version.
I do not know, what I have missed so far.
Any hints to get it analysed? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: solved it by:
```
[input]
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev  
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Comment: Could you add that as an answer Stefan

Comment: Yes, for sure... brb

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify the situation.
Hardware: iiyama ProLite T2435MSC-B2, intel nux i3, ubuntu 18.0.4 lts, kivy 1.10.1.
To get the touchscreen working in kivy app, you have to set the following input section in ~/.kivy/config.ini.
Important to say is, that "fullscreen = auto" has to be set, else noch touch is recognized in the kivy app.

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 0
log_level = debug
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon =
keyboard_mode = systemanddock
keyboard_layout = qwertz
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf']
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 20

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = auto
height = 1500
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 0
top = 0
width = 2000
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

[input]
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]
```